# Selenium with Mocha/Chai - How to return false is item does not exist in DOM

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js, chai

I'm currently using selenium-webdriver with Mocha & Chai in a JavaScript environment & I'm looking for a way to return a false value if an item does not exist in the DOM; basically to see if a user is logged in or not.

If they are logged in then the following exists in the DOM (and doesn't exist at all if your not signed in).

```html
<a class="account-panel-controls__link" role="link" id="sign-out-nav" data-log-out="">Sign out</a>
```

I'm looking for a way to find out if it exists & click it if present, otherwise I want to click something else (which only exists when the other snippet above does not).

```html
<a class="account-panel-controls__link" role="link" id="registration-sign-in-nav" data-log-out="">Sign in</a>
```

I've tried a few variations of the follow but it's gotten me nowhere. It works fine if the element with Id 'sign-out-nav' is present initially but if it's not then the test fails, saying that it was unable to find that element (I'm guess because it's not in the DOM at all?).

```js
driver.findElement(By.id('sign-out-nav')).isDisplayed().then(function (displayed) {
    if (displayed) {
        driver.findElement(By.id('sign-out-nav')).click();
    }
    else{
        driver.findElement(By.id('registration-sign-in-nav')).click();
    }
});
```

I've search a number of posts & tried stuff like .getSize() & seeing if it's over 0 but can't get anything to run that way. I've also tried using 'findElements' together with .length but it also returns a value of [Object object] and a length of 1 so I can't seem to tell the values apart.

Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: Is the element there in the HTML sent by the server? Or is it created by an JavaScript library? This is important because the technique you can use will vary depending on the case. In the former case you can skip waiting for the element because it is necessarily going to be in the page when you test for it. (And yes, using `driver.findElements` should work.)  In the latter case you have to wait for the element.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps in your instance, but using a webdriverio + mocha + assertjs + selenium, I used the following:

```
assert.doesNotThrow(() => { browser.getText('#registration-sign-in-nav') });
```

This works for the stack I work with, because when the element doesn't exist, it throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

To find elements on a page it is recommended to use *.findElement**s**()*:

```
// find an element on the page sample:
driver.findElements(By.id('sign-out-nav')) .then(found => console.log('Element found? %s', !!found.length));
```

Now if the ***.length > 0*** the element is found, you can continue with ***.elementIsVisible()*** & ***.elementIsEnabled()*** for additional validation and then do the clicks (as per your example) or anything you need.

Oh, not to forget, depending of what you want to do you might need to use indexes if there are multiple elements found either to the ***.findElement()*** in case you have only one.

Answer (score -1):

Selenium is really, really fickle when it is trying to find page elements. Surround your driver.findElement with a driver.wait() and see if that allows it to be found.

Comment: Apologies for just replying now; I don't believe it's to do with the wait as their is already one their that waits on the sign in/join part of the page loading. I've also surrounded it with driver.sleep()'s whilst testing but had no luck sadly.